# Mocking interface doesn't make sense?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am new to unit testing and it feels like I am missing something really big here. I would like to test the result of DoSomethingWithArray below:

```
class Traffic:ITraffic
{
    private HugeArray _hugeArray;
    public Traffic(HugeArray hugeArray)
    {
        _hugeArray = hugeArray;

    }

    public int DoSomethingWithArray()
    {
        var ret = 0;
        //Here some code that does something with big array and stores some integer values in ret
        return ret;
    }
}

class HugeArray
{
    //This is my custom data structure;
}

interface ITraffic
{
    int DoSomethingWithArray();
}
```

I am using Nunit and from what i read it's better to mock interfaces than to mock classes. My problem is that what I'd like to test is the CONCRETE functioning of DosomethingWithArray in the class Traffic, I am having a hard time conceptualizing how the interface ITraffic can fit in.
What am i missing here ?

**EDIT** Here is how I would test my class

```
[TestFixture]
public class TrafficTests
{
    private Traffic _traffic;
    private const int size = 1000000;
    private const int key = 1851925790;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var hugeArray = new HugeArray(size);
        //Some Setups to create an edge case, not  relevant to my question
        hugeArray.AddValue(size - 1, Int.MaxValue);
        hugeArray.AddValue(size - 2, key);
        //This is the object I want to test, 
        _traffic = new Traffic(hugeArray);
    }

    [Test]
    public void DoSomethingWithArray_Test()
    {
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() =>
                            {
                                var ret = _traffic.DoSomethingWithArray();
                                Assert.AreEqual(ret, 233398);
                            });
    }



}
```

my question is: Does this approach seem correct? is the object created for the the test okay or should i mock the interface ITraffic instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you're testing a public method of `Traffic`. That `Traffic` implements `ITraffic` doesn't matter. If you deleted `: ITraffic` from the class, so that it no longer implemented that interface, it wouldn't change the way you tested `Traffic` at all.

You're testing `Traffic`. We don't mock the thing we're testing. We mock the thing we're *not* testing.

Let's say I have this class which validates an address:

```
public class AddressValidator
{
    public ValidationResult ValidateAddress(Address address)
    {
        var result = new ValidationResult();

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.Line1))
            result.AddError("Address line 1 is empty.");
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.City))
            result.AddError("The city is empty.");

        // more validations

        return result;
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter whether this class implements an interface or not. If I'm testing this class there's nothing to mock.

Suppose I realize that I need to also validate the postal code, but in order to do that I need to perhaps query some external data to see if the city matches the postal code. Maybe it's different for different countries. So I write a new interface and inject it into this class:

```
public interface IPostalCodeValidator
{
    ValidationResult ValidatePostalCode(Address address);
}

public class AddressValidator
{
    private readonly IPostalCodeValidator _postalCodeValidator;

    public AddressValidator(IPostalCodeValidator postalCodeValidator)
    {
        _postalCodeValidator = postalCodeValidator;
    }

    public ValidationResult ValidateAddress(Address address)
    {
        var result = new ValidationResult();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.Line1))
            result.AddError("Address line 1 is empty.");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.City))
            result.AddError("The city is empty.");

        var postalCodeValidation = _postalCodeValidator.ValidatePostalCode(address);
        if (postalCodeValidation.HasErrors)
            result.AddErrors(postalCodeValidation.Errors);

        return result;
    }
}
```

The postal code validation is complicated enough that it's going to be in its own class with its own tests. When we test `AddressValidator` we *don't* want to test the postal code validator. We just want to test this class in isolation, and test the other class separately. Within `AddressValidator` want to make sure that `_postalCodeValidator.ValidatePostalCode` gets called, and that if it returns errors, we add them to the validation result.

We're *not* testing `IPostalCodeValidator` (or its implementations) here, so we mock it. For example, using [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart):

```
public void AddressValidator_adds_postal_code_errors()
{
    var postalCodeError = new ValidationResult();
    postalCodeError.AddError("Bad!");
    postalCodeError.AddError("Worse!");

    var postalCodeValidatorMock = new Mock<IPostalCodeValidator>();
    postalCodeValidatorMock.Setup(x => x.ValidatePostalCode(It.IsAny<Address>()))
        .Returns(postalCodeError);

    var subject = new AddressValidator(postalCodeValidatorMock.Object);
    var result = subject.ValidateAddress(new Address());

    Assert.IsTrue(result.Errors.Contains("Bad!"));
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Errors.Contains("Worse!"));
}
```

We're not actually validating the postal code. We're just saying, that for the sake of testing, the postal code validator is always going to return these two errors. Then we're making sure that `AddressValidator` calls it and does what we expect it to do with those errors.

That's basically what the mock is. It's a fake implementation of something that does something simple, like a canned response, so that we can make sure we handle that canned response the way we expect to. If `AddressValidator` handles the result correctly, then it works correctly. It's done.

To make sure the *real* postal code validator returns the correct result we can write tests for that class. This way each class does something simple and has tests to make sure it does its thing correctly. When we put them all together, it's much more likely that the whole thing will work. If we break the *implementation* of `IPostalCodeValidator` then the tests for that class will fail, but the tests for `AddressValidator` will still pass. That way we understand quickly which part has broken because they're all tested in isolation, so we don't have to run and debug lots of code trying to figure out where the problem is.